# Confidence Interval for Difference between two Paired Multinomial Distributions

Tags: confidence-interval, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution

I have two multinomial distributions $a$ and $b$ coming from a paired design (i.e., both multinomials are from the same subject, but the observations are IID within each multinomial). In my example I have 6 categories.

I want to have confidence intervals for the difference for each category. That is, for each of the 6 categories I am interested to know whether there is evidence that the difference differs from 0.

The following is an example in `R` of how my data looks:

```
a <- c(42, 63, 17, 8, 6, 12, 3, 1)
b <- c(6, 19, 6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 7)

a/sum(a)
## [1] 0.2763 0.4145 0.1118 0.0526 0.0395 0.0789 0.0197 0.0066

b/sum(b)
## [1] 0.125 0.396 0.125 0.042 0.021 0.083 0.062 0.146

a/sum(a) - b/sum(b)
## [1]  0.1513  0.0186 -0.0132  0.0110  0.0186 -0.0044 -0.0428 -0.1393
```

I want CIs for the difference values in the last line. Alternatively, I want to know if the difference for each category differs from 0.

Comment: Each individual proportion is binomial. Within each pair you're looking at pair of binomials (42 in the first category out of n1=sum(a), vs 6 in the first category out of n2=sum(b)). You could, for example, do a normal approximation for the difference in proportions and get a CI from that.

Comment: @Glen_b That would indeed work. Thanks. But I am still hoping for a simultaneous CI or something else that takes the full multinomial into account.

Comment: Oh, sorry I got the impression you were just after marginal intervals. In large samples a multivariate normal should work.